# Creating a new column with logical operators

Tags: python, pandas, apply, addition

I am trying to create a new column that would assign 'Five Or More', 'Minus Five Or Less', 'Between Five And Minus Five' with this other column as its input:

```
df['Change']
Out[196]: 
0       -0.398010
1       -3.980227
2        1.475952
3        0.000000
4       -2.043446

31514         NaN
31515         NaN
31516         NaN
31517         NaN
31518         NaN
Name: Change, Length: 30811, dtype: float64
```

I tried:

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'Five Or More' if (df['Change'] >= 5) else 'Between Five And Minus Five')
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'Minus Five Or Less' if (df['Change'] <= 5) else 'Between Five And Minus Five')
```

For both I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Thanks to anyone who helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df['new_column'] = df["Change"].apply(lambda x: 'Five Or More' if (x>= 5) else 'Between Five And Minus Five')
df['new_column'] = df["Change"].apply(lambda x: 'Minus Five Or Less' if (x <= -5) else 'Between Five And Minus Five')
```

Comment: Ok now the lambda function works good but it seems like these override each other, now rows that should have 'minus five or less' actually have 'between five and minus five'

Comment: second condition should be `x<= -5` instead of `x<= 5`.

Comment: Was able to get it done with 2 conditions inside the lambda function: `df['new_column'] = df['Change'].apply(lambda x: 'ABOVE 5' if x >= 5 else 'BELOW -5' if x <= -5 else 'BETWEEN 5 AND -5')`

Answer (score 0):

Change to this to fix your lambda function?

```
df['new_column'] = df['Change'].apply(lambda x: 'Five Or More' if (x >= 5) else 'Between Five And Minus Five')
```

In your lambda function, you need to be using x if you set lambda x, and the apply needs to be on a column - not the df itself. Check this out for more info https://datatofish.com/if-condition-in-pandas-dataframe/

Another way to do this is to create a function of your conditions and apply this function to your dataframe as follows:

```
def conditions(x):
    if(x>=5):
        return 'Five or More'
    elif(x<=-5):
        return 'Minus Five or Less'
    else:
        return 'Between Five And Minus Five'

df['new_column'] = df['Change'].apply(conditions)
```

Comment: Ok now the lambda function works good but it seems like these override each other, now rows that should have 'minus five or less' actually have 'between five and minus five'

Comment: So I think what you need to do is make a function with all your if and elses, and then apply that single function, because lambdas don't handle multiple ifs and elses well from what I've seen. I'll try to update my answer

Comment: I actually just learned it is possible to use 2 conditions or more inside a lambda function, this worked it out: `df['new_column'] = df['Change'].apply(lambda x: 'ABOVE 5' if x >= 5 else 'BELOW -5' if x <= -5 else 'BETWEEN 5 AND -5')`

Comment: Also your code says x<=5 when I think you mean x <= -5

Comment: Ok cool! I posted another way to do it also. One disadvantage of using too many conditions in a lambda is if you have many conditions it could get tough to track, I'd recommend using an apply over a function of conditions for better readability.

Comment: can you please give an example for better understanding? you mean applying a lambda twice?